# How to copy data from Master to multiple Slave in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I am trying to pull data(files) from git repository in the jenkins master and then push those files to multiple slaves.I am using Copy artifact to Slave plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) to copy the data from master to slave.But I am Unable to find out how to specify the name of the slave machines where the files have to be copied .Please help

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin copy some set of files from the master on the slave where the job is executed.

So once your job is running, the plugin will copy the files only on one slave...

(On the job, you can specify the slave in the "Restrict where this project can be run" section)

If your objective is to copy a set of files from the master to N nodes, maybe it's better to create a dedicated job on the master, and launch a batch/shell script to copy the files on your N slaves using network shared drives.

Another solution should be to have a dedicated job, using your plugin + the [Matrix configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin) to launch your job on several slaves.

I think the 2nd solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

If the task is to simply copy files from a git repo to the slave(s) where the job(s) are running, then that is exactly what the git plugin is supposed to do.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

It will pull the git repo files to the slave where the job is running.
Use multiple jobs or the Matrix configuration plugin if you want it to run on multiple slaves.

Comment: But when I try to pull the data from git into the slave machine it gives me "Error:Error Cloning remote repo origin "

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to specify the name of the slave, Once you configure the job, this plugin will copy the files on the node where your job is schedule to run.

Comment: When i specify the name of the slave in restrict where this project can be run section I get " Error:Error Cloning remote repo origin " and when I do not provide any slave name I get " Trying to copy files from the workspace on the master to the same workspace on the same master: No copy will take place."